# How to call all event handler subscribers and get their result?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, events, behavior

I have this snippet :

```
public static void Main()
{
    OnComparaison += LePlusPetit;
    OnComparaison += LePlusGrand;
    Console.WriteLine(OnComparaison(0, 9));
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static int LePlusPetit(object obj1, object obj2)
{
    int int1 = (int)obj1;
    int int2 = (int)obj2;
    return (int1 < int2) ? int1 : int2;
}

public static int LePlusGrand(object obj1, object obj2)
{
    int int1 = (int)obj1;
    int int2 = (int)obj2;
    return (int1 > int2) ? int1 : int2;
}

public delegate int Comparer(object obj1, object obj2);
public static event Comparer OnComparaison;
```

I have always as result `9`. So I need to know:

1. Does only the last subscribed event handler   is executed not all the subscribers?
2. If it is the case, How can I modify the code to make all the subscribed event handlers be executed when the event is fired?

Comment: How do you expect to get multiple return values?

Comment: @SLaks I mean in general way: for example if the event handlers write in the same file  and did not return values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [`EventName.GetInvocationList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get all the delegates subscribed to the event.

In that way, you can call each delegate and return the result, in whatever way you want.

```
foreach (Comparer c in OnComparaison.GetInvocationList())
{
    int result = c(0, 9);
}
```

This way, you can get all results for example:

```
IEnumerable<int> allValues = OnComparaison
                             .GetInvocationList()
                             .Select(x => ((Comparer)x)(0, 9));
```

Answer (score 6):

> Does only the last subscribed event handler is executed not all the subscribers?

No, all of them are executed but the result is the return value of last executed method.